# Extract data from tables stored in the form of an image and store in csv/excel file

Tags: conv-neural-network, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect tables stored in the form of an image in a multipage pdf and extract the contents of the table and store it in a csv/excel file.

I am able to detect and tabulate the contents of the tables where there are horizontal and vertical lines for row and column separation.
Eg, [table with horizontal and vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO3sB.jpg)

However, if the tables have no boundaries or any horizontal or vertical lines for row and column separation, I am unable to detect the table and extract the contents within the table.
Example of sample images:
[table with no horizontal or vertical lines 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNb7K.png)
[table with no horizontal or vertical lines 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYnDY.jpg)

There are two parts to this problem. Firstly, I need to detect tables from a multipage pdf and secondly, to extract the contents of the tables and store it in a csv/excel file.

Is there any existing solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could a tool like this: https://extracttable.com/. I used it before and it seems to be extracting table data accurately.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel. I know a few tools which do extract table data. However, I was looking for a neural network model or any other algorithm to start with to solve the issue.